# Show simple list of transactions in GA4?

Tags: google-analytics-4

In Universal Analytics, you could just go to Conversions -> E-Commerce -> Transactions to see a list of every single transactions sorted by transaction-ids.

How is this done in GA4?

It seems we are missing some transactions in GA4 and want to find out which transactions are not reported correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a free form exploration report with `Transaction ID`s as rows and `Purchase revenue` as values. Additionally, you could add `Date` as columns if you want to see which transactions happened on which dates.

You can create an exploration report from:

**Explore** -> Choosing a blank template (create a new exploration)